# Wordpress categories: how to display name, slug, description and link inside single post?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

What I want to do is, within `single.php`, pull different properties of the Category separately, like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <a class="CATEGORYSLUG" href="CATEGORYLINK">
            <i class="fas CATEGORYDESCRIPTION"></i>
            <span>CATEGORYNAME</span>
        </a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To produce an end product like this:

[image]

So that I can use:

1. the category **slug** as a CSS class, to style each category a unique color
2. the category **description** as a Font Awesome class (in this case, "fa-wrench"), to assign each category a unique icon

(For this project, each post will only be assigned a single category, but I suppose a future-proof solution would need to output ALL categories assigned to the post in this format.)

So I really just need to know how to individually pull:

1. Category slug
2. Category link
3. Category description
4. Category name

Comment: Would this help you? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/

Comment: Hmm, possibly? Do you know what values would I use for $field to grab the category properties I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function to get all of the categories assigned to that post object and loop through each one to create your icons etc.

Below is an example, I've called each individual variable so that you can see the object properties clearly.

This will also work if you only have one category assigned.

```
//get all categories:
$categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category');

//loop through categories
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    //get variables
    $slug   = $category->slug;
    $link   = get_term_link($category->term_id);
    $descr  = $category->description;
    $name   = $category->name;

    //echo your content
    echo '<a class="'.$slug.'" href="'.$link.'"><i class="fas '.$descr.'"></i><span>'.$name.'</span></a>';
}
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks for the help and clear code commenting!

Comment: Perfect :) Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using following code.

```
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Its return all the fields which you want for more info refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: Maybe add an edit, for future users, pointing out that [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) only works for the _category_ taxonomy :)

Comment: Yes just user want to get category data only :)